# Circuitikz wrongfully intersects node

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I have the following MWE:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks = true, citecolor=black, filecolor=black, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=black, linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}    
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}      
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}
\usepackage[european,cuteinductors,fetbodydiode]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[arrowmos]
        \draw (0,0) -- ++(0,0.75) to[short,i_=$a_1$] ++(0,0.5) to[short,-o] ++(0,0.5) node[right]{$b_1$} coordinate(b1);
        \draw [thick, dotted] (b1) -- ++(0,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the output [image: output]. As you can see, the dotted line intersects the node circle. How can I avoid this?

Comment: have alook at the answer below -- coordinate does not have any border -- nodes have some border

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As ever, [@js bibra](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/584491/38080) answer is ok. Just to explain a bit more what happens in the following (you can read a quite lengthy and full explication in the manual of `circuitikz`, section 5.1).

```latex
        \draw (0,0) -- ++(0,0.75) to[short,i_=$a_1$] ++(0,0.5) 
        to[short,-o] ++(0,0.5) node[right]{$b_1$} coordinate(b1);
```

When you use `-o`, `circuitikz` will add a node with the shape `ocirc` to the path. Nodes are drawn *after* the path is stroked; and the node is designed so that is filled with white. The coordinate `b1` is then set at the point where you arrived (the node you added with `$b_1$` has not moved it). Now

```latex
        \draw [thick, dotted] (b1) -- ++(0,1);
```

will draw the dotted line starting from `b1`, which is at the center of the `ocirc` node.

A different solution is to position the `ocirc` node *after* having drawn the dashed line.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[arrowmos]
    \draw (0,0) -- ++(0,0.75) to[short,i_=$a_1$] ++(0,0.5) 
        to[short] ++(0,0.5) node[right]{$b_1$} coordinate(b1);
    \draw [thick, dotted] (b1) -- ++(0,1);
    \node [ocirc] at (b1){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(BTW, notice that this is a real MWE).

A very similar problem is explained around page 174, in the FAQ:

[image]

Finally, as you comment, if you want to use the `north` coordinate of the pole, you have to put it explicitly so that you can name it:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}[arrowmos]
    \draw (0,0) -- ++(0,0.75) to[short,i_=$a_1$] ++(0,0.5) 
        to[short] ++(0,0.5) node[ocirc](b1){} node[right]{$b_1$};
    \draw [thick, dotted] (b1.norht) -- ++(0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Moreover, as [noticed by John Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/584488/tikz-circuitikz-wrongfully-intersects-node/584507#comment1469299_584491), now `b1` is a `node` reference, so the lines going out will start from the border anchor automatically:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[arrowmos]
    \draw (0,0) -- ++(0,0.75) to[short,i_=$a_1$] ++(0,0.5) 
        to[short] ++(0,0.5) node[ocirc](b1){} node[right]{$b_1$};
    \draw [thin,  red] (b1) -- ++(0,1);
    \draw [thin, blue] (b1) -- ++(1,1);
    \draw [thin, dashed] (b1) -- ++(-1,1);
    \draw [thin, dotted] (b1) -- ++(0.5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[arrowmos]
        \draw (0,0) -- ++(0,0.75) to[short,i_=$a_1$] ++(0,0.5) to[short,-o] ++(0,0.5) node[right]{$b_1$} node[inner sep=1pt](b1){};
        \draw [thick, dotted] (b1) -- ++(0,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thanks! But isn't it kind of a hack to use a node directly after a node and furthermore define the inner sep? I tried to use the anchor b1.north too but that hasn't worked aswell

Comment: if it serves the purpose its not a hack -- its ingenuity and being a yoda level operator

Comment: @Steradiant if you use `-o` the internal `ocirc` node is not accessible. You can put the node explicitly, with `node [ocirc](name){}` and then you can use `(name.north)`

Comment: @Rmano - or just (name).  Just tried it.

Comment: @JohnKormylo you're right - being a node name the line will automatically start at the border!